# Is it possible to enter a signed char into a scanf function

Tags: c, char, scanf, signed

I'm wondering if it is possible to save a signed char into a scanf function

```
/* Program to scan in a negative char */
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    signed char myChar;/* trying to save a char as a signed value */
    printf("Enter a signed char: ");
    scanf("%c", &myChar ); /*main part of the code to scan in a signed char */
    printf("You entered:  %c \n", myChar); /*returns a signed char*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is a "negative char"? Unadorned, a `char` is handled a signed (one byte) value. Adorn it as `unsigned char` and it becomes a one byte value capable of representing 0 to 255.

Comment: What I mean by negative char is "-1"

Comment: That's usually used for EOF. You can't type it as an actual character, and scanf will never return it

Comment: If you use a single-byte codeset such as ISO 8859-15, then the character ÿ (LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is code point 0xFF, which would be treated as -1 if assigned to a signed char variable.  The actual character represented by 0xFF varies by codeset, but a number of them use 0xFF for ÿ.  However, if you're working with UTF-8, then the byte values 0xC0, 0xC1, 0xF5..0xFF cannot appear in valid UTF-8 (and the ÿ character is represented by two bytes, 0xC3 0xBF).

Comment: @Fe2O3 it depends on the compiler and settings whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Re “Unadorned, a `char` is handled a signed (one byte) value”: C 2018 6.2.5 15 says “… The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.”

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    signed char myChar;
    printf("Enter a signed char: ");
    scanf("%hhd", &myChar ); 
    printf("\nYou entered:  %hhd \n", myChar); 
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f1785qbvK

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to enter a `signed char` into a `scanf` function?

Yes.  OP's `signed char myChar; scanf("%c", &myChar );` is OK.

More clearly, a user is entering *text*, and that can successful get saved in a `signed char`.

---

Details: You have 2 broad choices for `scanf()` to read text from the user and saves it into various objects.

**Read in a character and save that character code**

If you want to read input `"0"` and save that as the character `'0'` (e.g. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) 48), then use any of the 3 forms below.  `"%c"` expects a matching pointer as either `char *`, `signed char *`, or `unsigned char *`<sup>*1</sup>.

```
char myChar_plain;
scanf("%c", &myChar_plain ); 

signed char myChar_signed;  // OP like code
scanf("%c", &myChar_signed ); 

unsigned char myChar_unsigned;
scanf("%c", &myChar_unsigned );
```

**Read in numeric text and save that text as an integer**

If you want to read input like `"0"`, `"123"`, `"-123"`, `"+123"`, `" 123"`,  and save as an integer, albeit a small integer, then use any of the 2 forms below.

```
signed char myChar_signed;
scanf("%hhd", &myChar_signed ); 

unsigned char myChar_unsigned;
scanf("%hhu", &myChar_unsigned );
```

Instead of `d` and `u`, code can use `b, d, i, o, u, x, X, n` for other bases, etc.  `b` with C23.

---

Good code, in these cases, checks `scanf(...) == 1` to see if input and conversion were successful.

---

<sup>*1</sup> A `void *` is possible too.  Yet leave that for later.

> If no l length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, or `void` that points to storage large enough to accept the sequence.   C23dr § 7.23.6.2 12